# How do I compare multiple fields to multiple substrings?

Tags: sql, sql-like, presto

I'm working on a Presto query that checks multiple fields against multiple substrings to see if at least one field contains any of the given substrings. For example, let's say I want to check if either `column1`, `column2`, or `column3` contain `test`, `inactive`, or `deprecated`.

I could write multiple `LIKE` comparisons for each field and substring, but it seems a bit repetitive.

```
-- Functional, but cumbersome
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    column1 LIKE '%test%' OR column1 LIKE '%inactive%' OR column1 LIKE '%deprecated%'
    OR column2 LIKE '%test%' OR column2 LIKE '%inactive%' OR column2 LIKE '%deprecated%'
    OR column3 LIKE '%test%' OR column3 LIKE '%inactive%' OR column3 LIKE '%deprecated%'
```

I can simplify it a bit with `regexp_like()` but it's still a bit repetitive.

```
-- Functional, less cumbersome
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(column1, 'test|inactive|deprecated')
    OR REGEXP_LIKE(column2, 'test|inactive|deprecated')
    OR REGEXP_LIKE(column3, 'test|inactive|deprecated')
```

Ideally I'd like to have a single comparison that covers each field and substring.

```
-- Non functional pseudocode
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (column1, column2, column3) LIKE ('%test%', '%inactive%', '%deprecated%')
```

Is there a simple way to compare multiple fields to multiple substrings?

Answer (score 1):

You could search on a concatenation of the three columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    REGEXP_LIKE(column1+' ' + column2+' ' +column3, 'test|inactive|deprecated')
```

Also you could put the words your matching against as rows in a new MatchWord table, then be able to add/remove words without changing your query.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
 Data d 
WHERE 
EXISTS(
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM MatchWord w 
    WHERE 
        d.column1+' ' +d.column2+' ' +d.column3 LIKE '%' + w.word + '%'
)
```

Comment: concatenation has a risk in that the word being searched for may only be found because fields were concatenated.  'Bob' 'long' 'words'  and I'm looking for the word 'oblong'.  should'n return but it would here...

Comment: @xQbert thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated my answer with a space between each column.

Comment: While that will work index use will not